# How to Implement Angular 5 with YII2

Tags: angular, yii2, angular5

I am planning to build an enterprise application with yii2 and angular 5. I have only basic knowledge in angular 5 and I am not able to find how to plan architecture of the application. Should all the view contents should be generated from the angular or how the process will be?
Also how will be the server and client will be differentiated.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you mixing two different concepts.

## Client side

**Angular is a client-side framework**, there will be some static content, HTML, JS and CSS that will live somewhere in your server, for example, https://myapp.com, when the users request that address all the content needed to run the angular application will be served and the application will be run in the browser.

That *could* be the end of it if you didn't need to store/retrieve data from the server.

But it sounds like you will be storing data server side, the most common use case is to allow multiple clients to use that data. The common way to do that is to provide a [REST api](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) on the server side that different clients can use to access the data.

The use of angular as a client-side framework will give you some facilities when you need to consume data offered by a REST service. Do a Google search for *"consuming restful data with angular"*, there are many tutorials on the web.

## Server side

Now, **your client side framework does not care how you process that data on the server side**, using **yii2** is a valid option even though, for angular applications, using **node** on the server is more popular.

**yii** even offers some templates to get your RESTful service going, check [this page](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-quick-start) or, again, do a Google search for *"serving RESTful content with yii2"*.

## One way to do it

1. You could create your Angular application and serve it from your main domain, lets say that it is
   https://myapp.com
2. The client hits that domain and the app runs in the browser, now it needs to access some data from the database in the server.
3. Your yii2 application is accessible on some subdomain, for example
   https://api.myapp.com
4. The angular app makes a request to that subdomain, gets the data served as JSON and uses it. Or POSTs some data and it gets updated on the server.

The important thing to understand is that you are building **two applications** one that will run on the client side and one that will run on the server side. They will communicate through a REST api.

It sounds like you want to use Angular for the client side application and yii2 for the server side application but that you could be using any other technologies/frameworks and it should not affect how the opposite side access the data.

Comment: Thanks Raul, Yes I am planning to Yii2 as REST and Angular as client side. I will build it to dist file and then will use instead of having two servers.